# How to call a custom native JS function within a Vuejs 2 onclick event handler ?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to call custom JS functions within onclick event with Vuejs 2 and I get the below error. I omitted the curly braces for the prop used as per the migration guide.

- invalid expression: v-on:click.native="javascript:leo('resultList.matchHeaderEntityApi.eventIdPre','1');

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Call a vue method and call the native function from that method.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to move your native function call to VueJS event handler (in methods). In other words, just wrap.

Comment: I have nested vanilla JS which can not be easily wrapped and called from Vue components. I am looking for a way to keep legacy code within a Vue template but deprecating direct variable binding within attributes seems to have made this close to impossible...

Answer (score 1):

I usually rethink about putting native code in or Out of VueJs, sometimes using onclick is easier than on:click, if need call such these native functions in VueJs can call them by:

```
window.funcName()
```